# ModelMapper Set attribute of nested object

Tags: java, modelmapper

Is there a way configure model mapper to automatically map parent id to parent ids in nested child object?

Parent entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class ParentEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<ChildEntity> child;
```

Child entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class ChildEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Long parentId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

Parent DTO

```
public class ParentDto {
    
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<ChildDto> children;
```

Child DTO

```
public class ChildDto {

    private Long id;
    private Long parentId;
    private String name;
```

Currently Im using model mapper and it conversion works for the most part, and it creates a ParentEntity object with a list of ChildEntity object. Now Im looking for a way to populate the "parentId" field in each ChildEntity with modelmapper. Thanks in advance!

```
/*
{
  id: 1,
  name: "dad",
  children: [
    {
      id:10,
      name: "child",
    },
    {
      id:20,
      name: "child2",
    }
  ]
}
*/
modelMapper.map(parentDto, ParentEntity.class)
```

Comment: Is `parent_id` in `ChildEntity` not referencing `ParentEntity .id`? If so and comes from db, why do you need custom methods?

Comment: @Aman parent_id in ChildEntity is referencing ParentEntity.id, but when I use modelMapper.map it does not populate the list of ChildEntities with the parent id. Im guessing its due to the field names being different (id vs parent_id)

Comment: No, they are not. I mean, if  `ChildEntity.parentId` comes from db like you said, mapping should not be a problem.

Comment: @Aman when I try to map a parentDto to ParentEntity, the nested ChildEntities have null parentId. The conversion works, but I am trying to configure it so that the nested ChildEntities would automatically populate the parentId with the id of the parentEntity. I hope I am being clear.

Comment: The right way is to fix the broken link between the parent and child. You could write a `converter` otherwise, which gives you the mapping context so that you can customize the mapping as you like. But, unnecessary and useless complication will follow. http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/converters/

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is that when `ChildDto` is mapped you must have access to the `ParentDto` that has the `List` **children** in which the `ChildDto` to be mapped  is added. Otherwise the mapper does not know about that id.

Luckily you can access `ParentDto` with a little help from a `org.modelmapper.Converter`. Implement this interface like:

```
public Converter<ChildDto, ChildEntity> converter = new Converter<>() {
    private final ModelMapper mm = new ModelMapper();
    @Override
    public ChildEntity convert(MappingContext<ChildDto, ChildEntity> context) {
        // map it first normally
        ChildEntity ce = mm.map(context.getSource(), ChildEntity.class);
        try {
            // 1st parent is the List 2nfd is the ParentDto
            ParentDto parentDto = (ParentDto)context.getParent().getParent().getSource();
            ce.setParentId(parentDto.getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // well, maybe it was not ParentDto that expected to be the grandparent.
        }
        return ce;
    }
};
```

Then use it like:

```
ModelMapper mm = new ModelMapper();
mm.addConverter(converter);
```

and `ChildDto` that has no `parentId` should still be mapped to `ChildEntity` with `parentId`.